# How to 'break' a Gaussian pulse into discrete parts in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gaussian, pulse

I need to break down a continuous `Gaussian` pulse into `50 discrete parts` so I can use each of the 50 individual amplitudes in calculations. Here is what I've tried:

```
% Gauss pulse discretisation
tg = 20*10^(-3);         % pulse duration [sec]
B1 = 1;                  % max amplitude [muT]
t  = -tg/2:tg/50:tg/2;   % sampling times
sd = 0.25;               % pulse standard deviation
% pulse shape
p  = B1*exp(-((t-tg/2).^2)/(2*sd.^2));
plot(t,p);
```

However, the plot looks nothing like a Gaussian pulse of `20ms in duration`! Is there a problem with how the `sampling time` is defined? For example if the `sampling time` is defined as

```
t  = -1:tg/50:1
```

then the pulse does look like a Gaussian but it is broken down in 5001 parts. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: what do you mean by "breaking down to discrete parts"? You mean representing it as a discrete signal in the time domain?

Comment: For example, the 20 ms Gaussian shaped  pulse to be discretised into 20 separate 1 ms rectangular pulses, each with a variable amplitude and no delay between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your Gaussian to look like a Gaussian when you plot it, you need to make sure that you: (1) sample it around it's center, (2) your sampling interval is much smaller than the standard deviation (SD), and (3) you sample at least 2 or 3 SDs to each side, so you can see the decay. So in your example, since the Gaussian is centered around `tg\2`, and since your SD is `sd = 0.25` (btw the SD sets the pulse duration, not `tg`), extend the sampling interval, using the SD as a measure (and not `tg`), and move it so it is centered around the mean. It is easier to do all this using `linspace`:

```
t = linspace(-3*sd, 3*sd, 50) + tg\2;
```

If you further want a 20msec pulse duration, make `sd` in the order of 20msec, and not `tg`. Also note that "duration" is really a matter of definition for a Gaussian, as it extends to +- infinity. You have to define something like "pulse duration is from -2 SDs to +2 SDs", which means the effective pulse duration is defined according to how much the tail decayed.

```
% Gauss pulse discretisation
tg = 0;         % pulse center [sec]
B1 = 1;         % max amplitude [muT]
sd = .5*20*10^(-3);% half the pulse duration (msec)
t  = tg/2 + linspace(-3*sd,3*sd,50);  
% pulse shape
p  = B1*exp(-((t-tg/2).^2)/(2*sd.^2));
plot(t,p,'.-');
```

[image: Gaussian]

Comment: Right. So the **sd** sets the duration. It makes sense now. Thanks for the clear explanation.